# Streaming audio files from OneDrive using Background Audio Player in a windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive

I am trying to stream audio files using a windows phone app which plays background audio, the files reside in OneDrive. Looking at the OneDrive api i have figured ways to discover these files but to stream these files my hunch is that the OneDrive platform should be exposing a stream url through some api, as there are couple of apps which stream audio from OneDrive including the official OneDrive App itself.I have not been able to figure out this api.

I have done the same with dropbox using the GetMediaAsync api from the DropNet library, i was hoping for something similar with OneDrive api ? Has anyone figured this out ?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution,

so basically each file class on OneDrive is returned as a rest object, so all audio files have type [audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631831.aspx) and the audio object has a property source which gives the stream url

Comment: I am triying to do the same. I get the audio object and there I can see the "source" url. But when I try to read the content of the file I got a 404. I also add on the request the Authentication: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: @Abhilash I'm not getting source from audio object.. can you help me here?